# Android: Flip layout horizontally

Tags: android, android-layout

Say that my layout has a Button aligned to the left, and a TextView aligned to the right.

I would like that for some languages the layout will be displayed as is, but for others, the button should be on the right while the text should be on the left.

Is there some built-in or simple way to dynamically flip the layout views?

I could create a differenet layout and set the content view dynamically, but I would rather avoid this solution if any better could be suggested.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here in my sample code I am changing the layout on Button click You can put come login according to you need likewise

```
if laguage = "bl bla" call layout1();
else call layout2();
```

I am not creating the different layout but to same layout I am assigning different layout properties at dynamically.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:background="@drawable/cuadrogris"
        android:text="Button 1"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:background="@drawable/cuadrogris"
        android:layout_below="@id/btn1"
        android:text="Button 2"
        android:textSize="20sp" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnctrl1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:background="@drawable/cuadrogris"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Alignment 1"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnctrl2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:background="@drawable/cuadrogris"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"      
        android:text="Alignment 2"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>






public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    Button mbtn1;
    Button mbtn2;

    Button mbtncontroller1;
    Button mbtncontroller2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.relative_layout_activity);

        initializeControls();

    }

    private void initializeControls() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        mbtn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        mbtn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        mbtncontroller1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnctrl1);
        mbtncontroller2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnctrl2);


        //I am changing the layout here on Button clicks named(mbtncontroller1 and mbtncontroller2 respectively) 
        //You can do the same according to you condition if the language = "bla bla" this layout else that layout


        mbtncontroller1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                layout1();

            }
        });


        mbtncontroller2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                layout2();
            }
        });


    }

    private void layout1()
    {
         //These layout params actually help in accessing the properties of relative layout or Linear layout (here we are using Relative Layout)
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParamsleft = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParamsright = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                relativeParamsleft.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);// helps in assging properties of relative layout that actually we easily get in XML layout
                mbtn2.setLayoutParams(relativeParamsleft); // we need to set these layout params to the View.

                relativeParamsright.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
                mbtn1.setLayoutParams(relativeParamsright);

    }

    private void layout2()
    {

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParamsleft = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParamsright = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        relativeParamsleft.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        mbtn2.setLayoutParams(relativeParamsleft);

        relativeParamsright.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        mbtn1.setLayoutParams(relativeParamsright);

    }

    }
```